# Spring Security logout url not found after setting requireCsrfProtectionMatcher

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

After implementing a csrfProtectionMatcher in my Spring Security Configuration in order to just use CSRF tokens on UI facing REST methods I noticed that the logout method configured via

```
.and()//
.logout()//
.logoutUrl("/logout")//
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")//
```

was not found anymore (404!).

I figured out that I have to register a logoutRequestMatcher:

```
.and()//
.logout()//
.logoutUrl("/logout")//
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")//
.logoutRequestMatcher(request -> {
      RegexRequestMatcher logoutRequest = new RegexRequestMatcher("/logout", null);

      if (logoutRequest.matches(request)) {
          return true;
      }

      return false;
})//
```

Can anyone explain why? :)

Comment: if CSRF protection then logout method = POST